# DBD::Oracle, Cursors and Environment under mod_perl

Tags: apache, perl, environment-variables, mod-perl2, dbd

Need some help, because I can't find any solution for my problems with DBD::Oracle.

So at first, this is the current situation:

- We are running Apache2 with mod_perl 2.0.4 at our company

  - Apache web server was set up with a startup script which is setting some environment variables (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ORACLE_HOME, NLS_LANG)
  - In httpd.conf there are also environment variables for LD_LIBRARY_PATH and ORACLE_HOME (via SetEnv)
- We are generally using the perl module DBI with driver DBD::Oracle to connect to our main database

  - Before we create a new instance of DBI we are setting some perl env variables, too (%ENV). We are setting ORACLE_HOME and NLS_LANG.

So far, this works fine. But now we are extending our system and need to connect to a remote database. Again, we are using DBI and DBD::Oracle. But for now there are some new conditions:

- New connection must run in parallel to the existing one
- TNSNAMES.ORA for the new connection is placed at a different location (not at $ORACLE_HOME.'/network/admin')
- New database contents are provided by stored procedures, which we are fetching with DBD::Oracle and cursors (like explained here: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Oracle#Binding-Cursors)
- The stored procedures are returning object types and collection types, containing attributes of oracle type DATE

  - To get these dates in a readable format, we set a new env variable $ENV{NLS_DATE_FORMAT}
  - To ensure the date format we additionally alter the session by `alter session set nls_date_format ...`

Okay, this works fine, too. But only if we make a new connection on the console. New TNS location is found by the script, connection could be established and fetching data from the procedures by cursor is also working. Alle DATE types are formatted as specified.

Now, if we try to make this connection at apache environment, it fails. At first the datasource name could not resolved by DBI/DBD::Oracle. I think this is because of our new TNSNAMES.ORA file or rather the location is not found by DBI/DBD::Oracle in Apache context (published by $ENV{TNS_ADMIN}). But I don't know why???

The second problem is (if I create a dirty workaround for our first one) that the date format, published by $ENV{NLS_DATE_FORMAT} is only working on first level of our cursor select.

```
BEGIN OPEN :cursor FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(stored_procedure) END;
```

The example above returns collection types of object which are containing date attributes. In Apache context the format published by NLS_DATE_FORMAT is not recognized. If I use a simple form of the example like this

```
BEGIN OPEN :cursor FOR SELECT SYSDATE FROM TABLE(stored_procedure) END;
```

the result (a single date field) is formatted well. So I think subordinated structures were not formatted because $ENV{NLS_DATE_FORMAT} works only in console context and not in Apache context, too.

So there must be a problem with the perl environment variables (%ENV) running under Apache and mod_perl. Maybe a problem of mod_perl?

I am at my wit's end. Maybe anyone in the whole wide world has a solution ... and excuse my english :-) If you need some further explanations, I will try to define it more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that changes to %ENV made while processing a request don't seem to be honoured, this is because mod_perl assumes you might be running multiple threads and doesn't actually change the process environment when you change %ENV, so external libraries (like the oracle client) or child processes don't see the change.

You can work around it by first using the prefork MPM, so there aren't any threading issues, and then making changes to the environment using [`Env::C`](http://p3rl.org/Env::C) instead of the %ENV hash.